# Meu datepicker deveria funcionar somente no icon

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Tenho o seguinte Código:

```
$(".datePicker").datepick();
$("#IconDate").on("click", function () {
    $("#Date").focus();
})
```

Meu Html:

```
<div class="float-left gutter-right field-wrap">
    <label for="admissionEndDate">Data Admissão Fim</label>
    <span class="input-type-text">
        <input type="text" id="Date" name="admissionEndDate" class="datePicker hasDatePick" />
        <a href="#" class="datePicker" title="Calendário" id="IconDate">
            <img src="~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png" width="16" height="16" />
        </a>
    </span>
</div>
```

Está precisando que quando clica-se no icone aparece o data picker que estilizado, porém quando clico no input também aparece. não era para aparecer no click do input.

Answer (score 2):

Isso acontece por que o seu `datepicker` está relacionado com o seu `input` e também com o clique no seu ícone. Então terá que criar um `trigger` no seu `icon/button`, para somente ele acionar o seu `datepicker`. Link para documentação no final da resposta. Espero que isso lhe ajude.

**Para fazer do jeito que deseja irá ficar assim:**

```
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
      showOn: "button",
      buttonImage: "~/Content/images/icons/fugue/calendar-month.png",
      buttonImageOnly: true,
      buttonText: "Select date"
    });
  } );

// acao do button

$("#myButton").click(function() {
  $("#datepicker").datepicker("show");
});
```

[Link para a documentação referente](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#icon-trigger)

Comment: Conseguiu fazer?

Comment: não deu que esse datepiker e meio que personalizando parece então ele nem abre

Comment: Mas você pode inserir as personalizações dentro do próprio datepicker, na chamada de construção dele.

Comment: ai já não sei como, o problema teria que mudar em todas as views